# Firebird 2.0 transaction SELECT performance

Tags: sql, transactions, performance, firebird

In Firebird 2.0, is using an explicit transaction faster on a SELECT command than executing the command with an implicit one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All SQL commands (SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE etc.) can be executed ONLY within some transaction. You cannot run a command with out transaction being started prior to it.

Comment: This is confusing, as I'm working with the .net Firebird provider, and it has a FBCommand constructor that takes a transaction as parameter, and another constructor that does not. Furthermore, a transaction is not being started before you explicitly do it in the FBConnection instance, by invoking *dbcmd.BeginTransaction()*. I've tested the speed of INSERT and have seen significant improvement when using a transaction, compared to using FBCommand without the *transaction* parameter.

Comment: I edited the question to reflect the implicit and explicit transaction models of FBCommand.

Comment: "I've tested the speed of INSERT and have seen significant improvement when using a transaction, compared to using FBCommand without the transaction parameter."

In latter case every execution of INSERT statement involves implicit start and finish of internal transaction. That is why it takes longer time.

Answer (score 2):

Explicit and Implicit transaction are a feature of the component set you're using to access the database, not a feature of Firebird itself. As mentioned before, Firebird **always** does everything within a transaction. This has a couple of implications for you:

- Using a "Implicit" transaction can't be faster then using a "Explicit" transaction because from Firebird's point of view, a transaction is a transaction, doesn't matter who started it.
- Getting the best performance sometimes requires fine control over "Commits". While the "Implicit" transaction can't be faster then the "Explicit" transaction, the Explicit might be faster because you can control your StartTransactions and Commits. While you usually want to do all updates to a database within one transaction (so they all succeed or fail as a set) you sometimes want to split operations into multiple groups: If you need to bulk-insert many-many records, you probably want to Commit one every 1000 records or so.

Comment: Multam, Cosmine, si +1 pentru sfat.

Answer (score 1):

Firebird cannot execute SQL commands without a transaction.

PS: You get the best performance results if you commit transactions, rather than rolling them back. Even if you only called SELECT and changed nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Besides what was already said, take into account that the transaction can be:

- Read-Write
- Read-Only

For a SELECT it would be best to use a Read-Only transaction

*PS: There are other types of transactions but this two are the important ones for this topic.*

Answer (score 0):

Usually transaction adds some overhead. However, you should be careful if you do not have some default transaction started when you connect to Firebird.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the implicit transactions tend to default to Auto commit Retaining, so they should be slower.  You can always change the default behaviour.

But I would recommend using explicit transactions as Commit Retaining may cause you grief further down the line if it blocks too many transactions.  If it does then access to Firebird can slow down dramatically as it traverses through all the held-up/blocked transactions to determine the correct value of the data.

Here are some discussions on it

http://forums.devshed.com/firebird-sql-development-61/difference-active-transaction-863103.html

http://www.slideshare.net/ibsurgeon/3-how-transactionswork